# Return the specific contents from a field of data in the result-set of a select query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have select query that pulls a row of a data from a largeObject stored in a PostgreSQL table. The particular piece of data in the field is a html file.

I can output the name of the field of data into the console which appears as 16543 (for 16543kB).

So, my burning question is how I can return the actual contents (html) so that I can subsequently export it as one object and send it to the browser.

I am using node and express heres my source code so far:

```
var database = require('../database/postgresDB.js');
var pg = require('pg');
var html = {};

var connectionString  = "postgres://dabladmin:dabldem@localhost:5432/dablpatient";

var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();

var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM htmlfiles WHERE id = 1', function(err, result){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
      console.log(result.rows[0].htmlfile);
      html = result.rows[0].htmlfile;
      //return result.rows[0].htmlfile;
      //console.dir(html);
});

module.exports = html;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done directly. You need to export a function which will return the promise.

Following is an idea of how it can be done. Note: The code is not tested.

```
// htmlfile.model.js
const promise = require('bluebird'); // or any other Promise/A+ compatible library;
const initOptions = {
    promiseLib: promise // overriding the default (ES6 Promise);
};

const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);

// Database connection details;
const cn = {
    host: 'localhost', // 'localhost' is the default;
    port: 5432, // 5432 is the default;
    database: 'myDatabase',
    user: 'myUser',
    password: 'myPassword'
};
const db = pgp(cn); // database instance;

const getHtml = id => db.oneOrNone('SELECT * FROM htmlfiles WHERE id = $1', id);

module.exports = getHtml;
```

Inside `some.controller.js`:

```
const html_model = require('./htmlfile.model.js');

html_model.getHtml(1)
   .then(data => {
      if(data) {
          // record found
          res.send(data.htmlfile);
      } else {
          // record not found, do something else
        }
   })
   .catch(error => {
       // an error occurred
   });
```

Comment: Okay, thank you I understand what you are doing here I'll give it a try!

Comment: TypeError: html_model.getHtml is not a function

Comment: I passed this into the router directory file so I could send the results to the browser:     router.get('/new', function(req, res, next){
    html_model.getHtml().then(result => {
    res.send(result.rows[0].htmlfile);
  });
});

Comment: try changing "module.exports = getHtml" to "module.exports.getHtml = getHtml"

Comment: Cool that worked but now its throwing this error:  Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at html_model.getHtml.then.result... Its not reading the array property of '0'

Comment: try printing out the result to see its structure and pick the value you are interested in.